# Javascript to set value of dropdown field within Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page with a petition on it.  The petition is embedded from a petition providing website.  The embedding code creates an iframe, and loads the petition inside it.

The problem is that one of the petition values is "Country" and I am trying to change that default value to a different country after the petition has loaded within my page to make it easier for people who may sign the petition.

I have tried adding a function to the onload of the window, but it appears that it is still too early, before the embedded petition page is loaded.  Here is the code I currently have:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(e){ 
var ifr = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var ifrDoc = ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document;
var theCountry = ifrDoc.getElementById( 'sign_country');
var newValue = "ie"; // set to country
theCountry.value = newValue;
}
</script>
```

Any help?... perhaps I'm using the wrong event?

Comment: what error you getting in the console? if you debug - is 'theCountry' in your code defined?

Comment: i get an error when it's trying to find the iframe, because it's not there yet.  it loads AFTER the wondow.onload event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var newvalue = "1";
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
innerDoc .getElementById( 'sign_country').value = newvalue;
```

Your dropdown options should be like

```
<select id ="sign_country">
    <option value="0">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">India</option>
    <option value="2">USA</option>
</select>
```

Make sure that your newvalue should be value of the option in the dropdown.

Comment: Hey there... are you suggesting putting your code as is within script tags or within an event on the page?

Comment: ... just I'm not seeing how this is different to the above?... the problem is that the code is executing before the Iframe has embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the handler for the second 'onload' - for the iframe in your code:

```
window.onload = function(){ //main window loaded
    var ifr = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    ifr.onload = function(){ //ifame content loaded
      var ifrDoc = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
      var theCountry = ifrDoc.getElementById( 'sign_country');
      var newValue = "ie"; // set to country
      theCountry.value = newValue;
    };
};
```